# Issue with passing arguments to Powershell Inline script in Yaml Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am very confused with how to pass arguments to inline script (Powershell task or Azure Cli task) in yaml pipeline.
Can somebody explain in simple language with a simple example? I have seen so many articles about passing arguments to Powershell script (.ps1) but not to an inline script. My inline script below is disassociate and Associate a new NSG to an existing subnet:

```
     - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'JMeterAzureConnection'
          scriptType: 'ps'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
           $oldnsgid=az network nsg show -n armmc-nsg -g arm-armmcdemo-rg --query 'subnets[].id' -o tsv
           az network vnet subnet update --ids $oldnsgid --network-security-group "armmc-nsgv1"
```

When I run this, I get the below error during the pipeline run:
`ERROR: argument --ids: expected at least one argument`

Can you please help me what I need to do with this above issue?

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to properly format your [mcve].

Comment: I don't think output type `tsv` returns a comma-separated list of ids, required for the `--ids` argument.  In fact, any newlines returned in `$oldnsgid` might also throw that error.  Thus, ensure `$oldnsgid` is formatted correctly (and of the correct type) before using it in `az network vnet subnet update --ids`.  I might also try piping the output from `az network nsg show` into the `$oldnsgid` variable.